# Visual Studio 2013. Статическая линковка с библиотеками CRT

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Как заставить Visual Studio 2013 провести полностью статическую линковку с библиотеками CRT? Я выставил в настройках Code Generation Multi-Thread Debug, но зависимость от MSVCP120.DLL и MSVCR120.DLL осталась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать в настройках проекта в "C/C++ - Создание кода - библиотека времени выполнения" для отладочной версии /MTd, для релизной - /MT. Если у вас это не работает - значит вы что-то делаете не так, ибо способ проверенный и точно работает не в одном десятке проектов.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, Спасибо