# Отсутствует mcvcp140.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio

C++. Написал код на Visual Studio 2017. Собрал приложение как Release x86. Пробую запустить его на другом копьютере (установлена windows 7x64). Не запускает. Пишет Отсутствует mcvcp140.dll. Что в настройках Visual Studio отключить или включить, чтобы без этого компонента компилировался проект ? Про то, что надо переустановить пакет Visual C++ на той машине знаю, но хочу, чтобы и без этого работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо статически линковать с библиотеками CRT. Судя по всему у вас динамическая.

[Visual Studio 2013. Статическая линковка с библиотеками CRT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461582/visual-studio-2013-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-crt)

Comment: Да, точно, работает, но РАЗМЕР !!! в 10 раз больше файл весить стал.. :(

Comment: Ваш друг может поставить на ПК Visual C++ Redistributable. Его часто ставят программы, она содержит те самые dll, чтобы не ставить всю студию.