# Как скомпилировать exe в visual studio c++

Tags: c++, exe

Не могу найти способ скомпилировать exe, есть небольшой проект, у меня на компьютере .exe запускается спокойно, но на другом компьютере где нету visual studio не работает, пишет ошибку что не смог найти библиотеку dll, на другом компе  Visual C++ Redistributable все установлены. Помню раньше делал проект, и в настройках указывал как-то параметр, и с ним сборка работала нормально, но сейчас не могу вспомнить что за параметр был. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это вы наверное дебаг версию раздаете, которая линкуется с дебаг библиотеками

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/792137/195342

Comment: либо, как подсказывает @user7860670 у вас Debug, либо что-то стороннее, можно попробовать установить `depends` на другой комп, он показывает чего не хватает.
https://www.dependencywalker.com